# Magento - custom catalog/navigation

Tags: magento, templates, layout, navigation

I try to add a another menu (like top.phtml or left.phtml) on my footer, so I create a catalog/navigation/bottom.phthml but I don't understend how can I print it inside page/html/footer.phtml whit something like:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bottomnav') ?>
```

I know that I need to add a block on xml file, but I don't understand which file I need to edit and what I need to add.
How can I add this block?

Answer (score 1):

@kikko088 I think the answer above is incomplete, first of all is correct to add a new local.xml file but if  you want to add a new block in the footer you need to reference the footer and andd the other pace of code  but we need to add a correction under the code.

Code in your `local.xml`.

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer">
          <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="bottomnav" as="bottomnav"  template="page/html/bottomnav.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

As I reference to the footer and footer under the default phtml get automatically all the HtmlChild you don't need to go to the phtml and call the "bottomnav".

Let me know if this helps you.

Best,

Comment: ya i know that with the use of reference footer it will call automaticaly in footer but as per question @kikko088 want to use getchildhtml that s why i simplay create in block in call in phtml file. i think my answer is complete in my sense

Comment: But is not right in context of the question, @kikko088 want to display a catalog navigator under the footer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to add this block in `local.xml` located in

```
app>design>forentend>YOUR_PACKAGE>YOUR_DESIGN_layout>local.xml
```

if `local.xml` dosent exist in your layout folder then simplay create it and

add this block in `local.xml`

```
<block type="core/template" name="bottomnav" as="bottomnav"  template="page/html/bottomnav.phtml">
</block>
```

and simplay call this like

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bottomnav') ?>
```

it will call your file . Let me know if you have any query